# Browser open a new tab and disable url edit

Tags: javascript, html

In the html and javascript world is there a way to have a click on link, open a new tab, and disable url/address edit?

The code below does the open a new tab, but doesn't restrict the url/address edit.
How do I lock the url/address?

```
<a href="https://somewebsite.com" target="_blank">Feedback</a>
```

Comment: You may choose to hide the address bar in a new window. Use `window.open('https://somewebsite.com','Title','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');` in `onclick`. and make 'href` empty.

Answer (score 3):

You may choose to hide the address bar in a new window. Make `href` empty and use `onclick` function to open the window.

```html
<a href=""
    onclick="window.open('https://google.com'
    ,'Title','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');">Open</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user Javascript function:

```
window.open("http://someurl", "myPopup", 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=120,height=120')
```